# What are considered "voodoo fit indices" and "true"/"fake" standard errors? SEM CFA

Tags: stata, ordinal-data, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

In a conversation about fitting CFA with clusters and sampling weights (inverse probability weights) for ordered/ordinal/categorical data in R Lavaan, fit indices (GoF) were [referred to](https://groups.google.com/g/lavaan/c/CGq8dusdMgg/m/fBKnAQBJAAAJ) as "voodoo", and robust standard errors as 'true' and 'fake'. Stata does not provide such indices, perhaps for a reason. (I don’t know about MPlus or LISREL)

> You can compute the ("true") robust standard errors (not the fake Satorra-Bentler ones that assume the model structure is correct, pushing the standard errors down), you can compute cluster-corrected or survey-corrected standard errors by aggregating the scores over clusters. You don't get to compute the voodoo fit indices though. The two-step procedures employed in MPlus and lavaan (compute the polychoric correlations first; apply the SEM modeling to the correlation matrix) make it difficult to compute the standard errors.

Is anyone (including Stas K.) able to unpack, discuss, or explain at least some part of this issue? For instance - how established is it that fit criteria can be computed for such data? - is there evidence it is feasible? - is there reasoning suggesting it would make sense or not make sense? - is there public domain evidence for the validity of the procedure used in Stata?

Comment: Consider continuing your conversation on the thread you linked to.  You haven't provided a definition of the quoted "terms" in your title, and the questions are very general.  I think you just need to start scouring the literature on SEM-fit evaluation to learn the current state of things (which is always in controversy).

Comment: Dr. @Terrence, thanks for input. I ask because I cannot define it but refer to the concepts being used. They are obviously slang or short hand for something much more extensive. But perhaps it could be explained somewhat roughly in lay terms. I thank that would be of interest to others. However, I will bring the question forward on the lavaan group on your invitation (was not sure that was appropriate, feeling like hijacking anothers thread)